# tomcat7-maven-plugin couldn't locate the property file on classpath

Tags: maven, tomcat7, integration-testing

I am trying to use "tomcat7-maven-plugin" to run integration test on war file. WHen the war gets dployed it basically load spring applicaitoncontext which in turns expect property files on classpath. In regular tomcat instance I keep property files somewhere on my machine and then configure catalina.properties -> common.loader to point to that directory. But I don't know how to achieve that with this plugin.

here's the plugin config I tried:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- port>8090</port -->
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                <!-- systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <maven.tomcat.port>8080</maven.tomcat.port>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties -->
                <!-- if you want to use test dependencies rather than only runtime -->
                <useTestClasspath>false</useTestClasspath>
                <!-- optional if you want to add some extra directories into the classloader -->
                <additionalClasspathDirs>
                    <additionalClasspathDir>${basedir}/src/test/resources</additionalClasspathDir>
                </additionalClasspathDirs>
                <additionalConfigFilesDir>${basedir}/src/test/resources</additionalConfigFilesDir>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <!--  goal>run</goal -->
                        <goal>run-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalClasspathDirs>
                            <additionalClasspathDir>${basedir}/src/test/resources</additionalClasspathDir>
                        </additionalClasspathDirs>
                        <additionalConfigFilesDir>${basedir}/src/test/resources</additionalConfigFilesDir>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>shutdown</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: How is Spring loading these properties? If you're using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` you could add a file pattern for which you make a file available through your `src/test/resources`. The latter will be part of your class path after all. I can give a more extensive example if this seems to be what you're missing.

Comment: I use "classpath:{env}.properties" which I can't change as it gets loaded from container classpath in production. Anyhow I ended up using Surefire/Cargo to do both unit/container integration tests. TCargo has this simple configuration which works like a charm:  <configfiles>
                            <configfile>
                                <file>${basedir}/src/test/resources/{env}.properties
                                </file>
                                <todir>lib</todir>
                            </configfile>
                        </configfiles>

Comment: I dont understand why additionalClasspathDirs or additionalConfigFilesDir didn't work in tomcat plugin. Am I missing something there? I can see file copied in conf folder in exploded war under tomcat (by plugin)..but conf folder don't seem to be on classpath. By the way, src/test/resources is in java build path since it has entry in .classpath file on my porject folder but it's not part of war artifact so you have to tell plugin/tomcat externally where to look for prop files.

Comment: I thought `src/test/resources` would already be on the classpath, regardless of `additional...`. I never used those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We encountered same problem. I filed a JIRA for that (MTOMCAT-246). Turns out it works that way only for tomcat7:run goal, not for the run-war-only. They plan to fix it in the 3.0 release. We have a workaround for that in place, see below.

One way to achieve it is to package your property files as jar file and include them in the dependencies of the plugin.

In our case that meant creating a maven module out of our config folder in the parent project (which stored configs for various environments):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>distribution.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <!-- add property replacement to state environment name -->
            <directory>build</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

The distribution.xml looked like:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>config</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

And then in the plugin section:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
....
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.your.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You add a link to the config.jar file which contains those property files.

Comment: This is a nice workaround. We use the same solution (adding a dependency to the plugin) when we configure JNDI datasources that use a custom factory. In a regular Tomcat we would have to copy the jar into <tomcat>/lib. The same thing can be achieved with the tomcat7 plugin simply by adding the dependency.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-246 there the last commenter claims he makes it work without an 'artificial' dependency 

<profile>
    <!-- Enable this profile to run the application with "mvn tomcat7:run -Pdev. -->
    <id>dev</id>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource><directory>instance-config/dev</directory></resource>
            <resource><directory>src/main/resources</directory></resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>